# onselect in one combo it changes data dynamically in other combo?

Tags: ajax, jsp, dynamic, load, onchange

Hello sir I am new to the jsp and ajax world. my problem is
 If i select one combo option then it should change the other combo options dynamically without submit button press. 
for example if i select the country  then it should shows their states in other combo.
I am using servlet & JSP and MS-ACCESS as backend.  please  reply as soon as possible.

THANKING YOU....

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. A piece of JSP which returns a string which can be parsed in javascript to create a list of possible combobox items (value, name) to select in the SECOND combobox, based on a VALUE which can be selected in the FIRST combobox
2. A piece of javascript which receives the onChange event of the FIRST combobox and uses the then selected value to create a XMLHTTP-request to your JSP (at 1)
3. A piece of javascript which you can pass to the XMLHTTP-request onReadyStateChange event to execute, which reads/parses the parseable string (from 1) and fills the second COMBOBOX with those values

Good luck